# SQLite slower than expected when querying

Tags: swift, sqlite, grdb

I have a fairly large (3,000,000 rows) SQLite database. It consist of one table.
The table has an integer id column, a text-based tag column, a timestamp column saved as an int, and 15 double number columns.
I have a unique index on the tag and timestamp columns, since I always look entries up using both.

I need to run though the database and do quite a few calculations. Mainly calling a bunch of select statements.
The complexity of the select statements is really simple.
I am using the GRDB library.

Here is an example query.

```
do {
    try dbQueue.read { db in
        let request = try DataObject
            .filter(Columns.tag == tag)
            .filter(Columns.dateNoDash = date)
            .fetchOne(db)
    }
} catch { Log.msg("Was unable to query database. Error: \(error)") }
```

When I run the debugged trace on the queries my program generates (using `explain query plan`), I can see that the index is being used.

I have to loop over a lot of queries, so I benchmarked a segment of the queries. I am finding that 600 queries roughly take 28 seconds. I am running the program on a 10-core iMac Pro. This seems slow. I was always under the impression that SQLite was faster.

The other code in the loop basically adds certain numbers together and possible creates an average, so nothing complex and computationally expensive.

I tried to speed things up by adding the following configuration to the database connection.

```
var config = Configuration()
config.prepareDatabase { db in
    try db.execute(sql: "PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY")
    try db.execute(sql: "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
    try db.execute(sql: "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE")
    try db.execute(sql: "PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY")
    try db.execute(sql: "PRAGMA cache_size = 2048000")
}
let dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: path, configuration: config)
```

Is there anything I can do to speed things up? Is GRDB slowing things down? Am I doing anything wrong? Should I be using a different database like mySQL or something?

Thanks for any tips/input

Comment: SQLite is *light*, not fast. It's an embedded database, using your application's process, RAM etc. It won't use multiple cores the way server-based databases do. Besides, the number of queries doesn't matter as much as the *type* of queries, and how much data they need to scan, return etc. If the tag and date fields have low selectivity, the database will have to read and return a lot of data anyway.

Comment: Instead of executing 600 queries returning 1 item, execute 1 query that retrieves the 600 items you want

Comment: I tried to reduce the number of queries (by bundling) them in other parts of the app, but did not really notice a significant increase in speed. The queries seemed to simply take longer.

Comment: On average, 600 queries in 28 seconds, means 47ms for each query on a table of 3000000 rows. Why do you consider this slow?

Comment: What do you mean bundling? Executing 600 quickly one after the other is still 600 seeks, scans etc. `SELECT * from table where tag in (a,b,c,d,...) and date between a and b)` is a single query that returns all the data at once

Comment: @forpas the overall number *is* slow but it's mainly due to executing multiple queries.

Comment: I can bundle 5 queries together, since they all will have the same tag, but different datestamps, so something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag = 'abc' AND (dateNoDash = 1234.. OR dateNoDash = 4567.. OR dateNoDash = 9876.. OR dateNoDash = 3456.. OR dateNoDash = 5678..)`. I then sort out the results in code. Reduction of the queries to 1/5 of the original number of queries. I was only able to shave 1 second off the execution time. Ergo 120 of these queries 27 sec.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried to test your prior statement and combined all my queries (previously roughly 28K single queries) into one very large query. The benchmarking above (600 queries) was my attempt to partition the queries to debug the process. This took a total of 127 seconds, returning 21K results. That is the speed I was looking for. You are right - to keep SQLite speedy, don't shy away from huge queries.

Comment: Another option is to create another table with `tag` and `date` fields covered by an index, fill it with the tag and dates you want and join with the original.

Comment: I purposely made my table "wider" - I always thought `JOIN` statements were too "expensive" and would slow down queries? Does SQLite work better with smaller tables?

Comment: Hello @Joseph. GRDB 5.7.4 has introduced a performance regression, so maybe try with GRBD 5.7.3. Otherwise, SQLite is *both* lite and fast. And GRDB attempts at providing the most of it: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/wiki/Performance Maybe, if you spot something odd, open an issue in the GitHub repository, with profiling information from Instruments.

Comment: @GwendalRoué Really love GRDB - Thank you for making it. Can you point me to the fastest and most effective way to save (updating) 10K+ objects when looping through them? I think that updating my objects is another huge bottleneck in my algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: Joseph, https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/926 is for you.